# Trimming first character to match another value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pretty straightforward query that's working except for one `CASE WHEN` statement.

I'm select records with phone numbers and comparing them to numbers in another table. This works fine for inbound calls, but the outbound calls Don't get picked up even though we've verified that many of them exist. The first issue was that outbound calls automatically have a '1' placed in front where the inbound don't. I trimmed the first character from `a.finallycalledpartyno` which is the outbound number we're selecting, but it still isn't working.

I'm wondering if I'm not using it properly or if there's a better way. The affected column is a VARCHAR(45) if that makes much of a difference. But if I research the record I find many that show as known on a phone number for inbound and the exact same number in outbound won't be marked as known, so I feel like the format of outbound numbers is the only logical difference.

Any help much appreciated.

```
            SELECT
                Recieved_Known
                , Outbound
                , Outbound_Known

                FROM (
                  SELECT distinct
                   case when LEGTYPE1 = 2 and answered = 1 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as Recieved_Known
                   , CASE WHEN /*ANSWERED = 1 AND*/ LEGTYPE1 = 1 then 'x' ELSE '' end  AS Outbound
                   , case when LEGTYPE1 = 1 and TRIM(leading '1' FROM a.FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO) = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as Outbound_Known

                  FROM session a
                        LEFT JOIN known_numbers k ON a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number
                            WHERE a.ts >= '2017-11-30'
                            and(a.CALLINGPARTYNO in (select extension from users) 
                      OR a.finallycalledpartyno IN (select extension from users))
                      ) x
                      order by extension;
```

Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d5b39/2

Comment: Some sample data would probably make this a bit easier to research

Comment: hiw many leading 1 you have in your phone number  ... if you need  only remove the first  .. you should use a substr..

Comment: Sorry, I've added a fiddle as well now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what is wrong with your TRIM function, but you could used the following CASE WHEN statement as an alternative:

```
CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 1 
   and Substring(a.FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO,2,Len(a.FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO)) = k.phone_number 
       then 'x' ELSE '' end as Outbound_Known
```

it should do the same thing you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Just making sure I understand, the 2 means it starts at position 2?

Comment: Correct. This is assuming that every record in the a.FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO column contains the leading 1. The 2 will tell the SUBSTRING function to start at position 2 and return everything after that.